# regex route filters some /string after slug url

Tags: php, regex

i want just allow string /more /next & /1  after the slug
ex :

- https://loremipsum.com/post/hello-world/more
- https://loremipsum.com/post/hello-world/next
- https://loremipsum.com/post/hello-world/1

this is what i've try :

```
/([a-z0-9]+)([A-Za-z\-0-9]+)(.*)[/]{0,1}(more|next|[0-9]+){0,1}[/]{0,1}
```

the regex is still work when i open the page like https://loremipsum.com/post/hello-world/sdfsdfsdf
note i use (.*) on the regex for allowing any character on the slug so it will automaticly redirect.

Comment: Try `/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/(more|next|[0-9]+)/?$`, see https://regex101.com/r/4HwYgH/1

Comment: Or, `/([^/]+)/(more|next|[0-9]+)/?$`, see https://regex101.com/r/4HwYgH/2

Comment: isee its work, but more/next & /1 is optional that is why i use this {0,1}
my slug can allow anything so i still need this grouping (.*)

Comment: You could make the pattern a bit more specific `^https?://\S*?\.com/post/hello-world(?:/(?:more|next|\d+))?$` https://regex101.com/r/do2QYj/1

Comment: but how to still allow any character in the slug like this https://loremipsum.com/post/hel%C2%A0lo-world , /more /next /1 and dissallow /sdfsdf .

Comment: example : https://regex101.com/r/bm0Y7v/1

Answer (score 1):

I hope this regex can help you :

```
 \/([a-zA-Z]+)(.*)[\/](more|next|[0-9]+) 

 \/([a-zA-Z]+)(.*)[\/](more|next|[0-9]+){0,1}[\/]{0,1}
```

Also be carefull about evil regex, each regex is potentially a open door for DDOS attack on you website.

I tried your regex on :  https://regexr.com/
It's a good tools for testing your regex